# If g*f is differentiable at x0, then

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

> **True or False**: If $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, and $g$ is differentiable at $y=f(x_0)$.

I don't understand why if $(g\circ f)(x_0)$ is differentiable, then the following is not true: $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $g$ is differentiable at $y_0=f(x_0)$.

Will the first statement not be true and why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule says that if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, and $g$ is differentiable at $y_0 = f(x_0)$, then $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $$(g \circ f)'(x_0) = g'(y_0) f'(x_0)$$ This question is about reversing some of the implications in that statement.

If you compose a misbehaving function with a constant function, you can cover up its misbehaving. Try $f(x) = |x|$ and $x_0 = 0$. You know $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0$.

Now let $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$. Then $g'(0) = 0$. But also, $(g \circ f)(x) = 0$ for all $x$. This means $(g \circ f)'(x_0) = 0$, as well.

So here we have a situation where the composition is differentiable, but one of the components is not.

Comment: Likewise if $f$ is constant and $g$ is not differentiable. Therefore we can't say anything about $f$ and $g$.

Comment: It is possible that both functions are bad but their composition is fine. For example let $f(x)=0$ for nonrational  numbers $x$ and $1$ for rational numbers.  Then $(f\circ f)(x)=1$ for any $x.$